# What came before quantum theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, discrete

My professor explained today that the idea behind quantum theory is that particles have quantized energy states. To an undergrad like me, this is kind of strange. Wouldn't it always make sense that a particle should have a **value** for an energy level? Was it not "quantized" before?

It kind of sounds like "Before quantum theory, we just kind of avoided thinking about whether or not particles have energy values that we could represent with a value. Now we just kind of do that."

Comment: In Quantum Theory **bound** electrons can only have one of a set of energy values.  Free electrons can have any kinetic energy.

Comment: Free particles don't have quantized energy states, they can take on a continuum of possible energies. Atoms do have nearly quantized energy states and what led to the development of quantum mechanics were the observations of line spectra and the structure of the black-body spectrum, which requires the assumptions of quantized energy states. As to the historical development... it's easy to find on the internet, so your question is based on insufficient research effort.

Comment: I feel that you misinterpreted the word "quantize".

Comment: The main things that came before quantum theory were Newton's laws and Maxwell's equations. And when you apply those to electrons and nuclei, you get the prediction that atoms are impossible, because electrons would just fall into the nucleus and stay there. Quantum innovations like the uncertainty principle (wavefunctions) and the exclusion principle (fermion statistics) solved this problem, as well as explaining atomic spectra, molecular bonds, and so on.

Comment: Imo, "insufficient research" is always in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wasn't just the fact that a value or (quanta) was assigned it was also that a particle or packet was assigned instead of a wave. Max Plank while studying black body radiation couldn't get the wave theory to work and developed his idea of a constant (now called Planks constant). Later Einstein added the quanta or photons packets etc. Like CuriousOne said its easy to find on the internet.